# placing two texts line by line between each other with coloured background in android

Tags: android, text, textview, multiline

I have two texts (large amount) and want to display them in one activity, line by line, between each other like that in the code, actually this two texts, are a text and its translation to other language.
i write each line in a seperate TextView to do that, and i know its not the right and efficient way, because it can not support different screen sizes and needs large amount of TextViews for large texts.
my code in activity_layout is:

```
    <TextView android:text="@string/En_Line1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#AADDBB"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <TextView android:text="@string/Sp_Line1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#BBBBBB"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <TextView android:text="@string/En_Line2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#AADDBB"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <TextView android:text="@string/Sp_Line2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#BBBBBB"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <TextView android:text="@string/En_Line3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#AADDBB"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <TextView android:text="@string/Sp_Line3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#BBBBBB"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <TextView android:text="@string/En_Line4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#AADDBB"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <TextView android:text="@string/Sp_Line4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#BBBBBB"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <TextView android:text="@string/En_Line5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#AADDBB"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <TextView android:text="@string/Sp_Line5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#BBBBBB"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <TextView android:text="@string/En_Line6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#AADDBB"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <TextView android:text="@string/Sp_Line6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#BBBBBB"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
<TextView android:text="@string/En_Line7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#AADDBB"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
<TextView android:text="@string/Sp_Line7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#BBBBBB"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
<TextView android:text="@string/En_Line8"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#AADDBB"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
<TextView android:text="@string/Sp_Line8"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#BBBBBB"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

Comment: Use Spannable String for this types of work. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [Spannable String](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html):

```
  // this is the text we'll be operating on
    SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");

    // make "Lorem" (characters 0 to 5) red
    text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 5, 0);

    // make "ipsum" (characters 6 to 11) one and a half time bigger than the textbox
    text.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 6, 11, 0);

    // make "dolor" (characters 12 to 17) display a toast message when touched
    final Context context = this;
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "dolor", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
    text.setSpan(clickableSpan, 12, 17, 0);
```

[Example is from here](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring)

Comment: thank you Loyal, i know this, but for large text i need to use for loop in main activity to do such a thing, and its maybe slow down loading of activity. also i dont know how to seperate lines to support all devices, you know in large screens we can see more words in one line than a small screen.

Comment: @user4949420 Why not just let your text view wrap? You don't need a text view for each line...

Comment: Becaause there are two different texts, (like a text and its translation) that should be placed line by line between each other, and I can not just do it in one text view.I will be glad if you tell me how?

Comment: Actually i know how to colorize background and foreground with spannable string or htmlform, but placing two texts line by line! Thats what I dont know!

Answer (score 0):

```
String source = "This is example text";
Spannable out = new SpannedString(source);
StyleSpan boldSpan = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
StyleSpan boldSpan2 = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
out.setSpan(boldSpan, 1, 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
out.setSpan(boldSpan2, 9, 12, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```